# Can I simplify this query by removing the joins?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns: `entry_id` and `cat_id`, with data that looks like:

entry_id | cat_id
1               2
1               3
1               4
1               5
1               6
1               7

For this example, imagine the `cat_id`s are split into arbitrary groups of `(2,3)`, `(4,5)`, `(6,7)`.

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.entry_id 
FROM 
    items t1 
JOIN 
    items t2 
ON 
    t2.entry_id = t1.entry_id 
JOIN
    items t3
ON 
    t3.entry_id = t1.entry_id
WHERE 
    t1.cat_id IN (2, 3) 
AND 
    t2.cat_id IN (4, 5)
AND
    t3.cat_id IN (6, 7)
```

Which returns an `entry_id` of `1`.

The query works, but depending on the situation, the number of self joins will be between one and five. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't have a variable number of self joins - is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you just combine the arbitrary groups into one .. wouldn't that have the same effect?

Comment: your example isn't exceptionally clear.  entry-id is 1 for all of your rows.  Are you just asking for how to select a distinct value for some cat-id's, which you can do using an IN clause?  Or is there some other logic at play here?

Comment: I think he's looking to select those `entry_id`s which have a `cat_id` from each group.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard is correct. I should've used more than just one value for entry_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select entry_id
from items
group by entry_id
having count(distinct case
                          when cat_id in (2,3) then 1
                          when cat_id in (4,5) then 2
                          when cat_id in (6,7) then 3
                      end) = 3
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a34ab2/1).

Answer (score 0):

As answered from a somewhat similar question, a user was dynamically building his query and didn't KNOW how many criteria were going to be applied.  By having the JOIN and WHERE combinations made his difficult, but this similar alteration made it very easy to implement...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      t1.entry_id 
   FROM 
      items t1 

         JOIN items t2 
            ON t1.entry_id = t2.entry_id
           AND t2.cat_id IN (4, 5)

         JOIN items t3
            ON t1.entry_id = t3.entry_id
           AND t3.cat_id IN (6, 7)

   WHERE 
      t1.cat_id IN (2, 3)
```

The where applies the primary criteria for the categories, then be each join having the matching key and its criteria will either allow or not the join to have such record and give results you want...  The automation is just building the JOIN/ON/AND component and just keep upping the alias T2, T3, T4 as needed.